# Error: Namespace "iOS" does not exist in Unity.Notifications

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, notifications

I added

```
using Unity.Notifications.Android;
using Unity.Notifications.iOS;
```

to my script.

VisualStudio says everything is fine, the intellisense sees fields from both namespaces fine, and I'm able to run in the editor fine.

But then when I try to build for Android to test of my phone, it says the namespace iOS does not exist in Unity.Notifications.

If I remove all iOS code it builds fine.

Answer (score 3):

Well it makes totally sense that the according namespace only exists on a certain target platform. It doesn't sound like a big surprise that a namespace called `iOS` is not included in a build for `Android` and viceversa..

Have a look at [Platform depended compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

and remove according code blocks using [`#if` preprocessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

```
#if UNITY_IOS
    using Unity.Notifications.iOS;
#elseif UNITY_ANDROID
    using Unity.Notifications.Android;
#endif

...

#if UNITY_IOS
    <Code for IOS>
#elseif UNITY_ANDROID
    <Code for Android>
#endif
```

They did probably exactly the same wrapping the entire namespaces in such preprocessors in order to exclude them on the according target platforms.